# List index out of range in python

Tags: python

```
data =[]
ips =[]
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    data +=[line.split()]
    if line =='':
        ips=[x[0] for x in data]        
        break
```

Comment: I can't find a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check for the empty line after appending the splitted line to data. `.split()` on an empty line returns an empty list.

`x[0]` on an empty list produces an IndexError.

```
data +=[line.split()] # equal to data.append([])
if line =='':
    ips=[
         x[0] # Access to the first element of every list in data.
         for x in data
        ]
```

You need to check for the empty line before appending it to `data`